# Getting Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. .exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

getting Exception

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

code:

```
 HotelDealsDataClassesDataContext hotelDealsDataContext = DatabaseHelper.GetHotelDealsDataContext();
 hotelDealsDataContext.spInsertAsyncHotelDealFeedRequestData(Utility.GetBinaryData(hotelDeal), DateTime.Now);
```

stack trace:

```
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()  
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) 
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()  
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()  
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)    
 at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)  
 at Tavisca.TravelNxt.Deals.DataFeeders.DataAccessLayer.HotelDealsDataClassesDataContext.spInsertAsyncHotelDealFeedRequestData(Binary hotelDealData, Nullable`1 addDate)
```

Comment: This question may seem odd but, do you dispose of your database connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception tells you that you have exhausted the connection pool , means all connection pool is full and all connection are in use, and command string timeout is reached before getting a connection (default timeout is 15 seconds).
As RePierre suggested check if you are disposing your connection properly .

Try to open connection as late as possible and close/dispose as soon possible.

General recommendation : - Always prefer <kbd>[USING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)</kbd> statement for opening all connections 
                           it  ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

[TimeOutExpired](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/08/25/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-obtaining-a-connection-from-the-pool.aspx)